# Getting error while installing OCPP in Python2.7

Tags: python, pip, package, ocpp

Iam trying to install OCPP in Python 2.7 using following command and getting the error shown below. plz help to resolve the issue

```
C:\Python27>python -m pip install ocpp
Collecting ocpp
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/f8/f3222edf8cf0f1a7373c9d5b0be0974959b3cf302906f0c59fe8bf4071f7/ocpp-0.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\vijaya~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yaigdj\ocpp\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        with open(path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\vijaya~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yaigdj\ocpp\
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I installed python 3.8 and reinstalled OCPP. After that Iam trying to simulate the central system and charge point of PyPi OCPP given in the following link https://pypi.org/project/ocpp/. Central system code runs without any error. but while compiling the charge point code i am getting the following error

```
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
====================== RESTART: C:/Python38/ocppserver.py ======================
INFO:root:WebSocket Server Started

====================== RESTART: C:\Python38\chargepoint.py =====================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\chargepoint.py", line 39, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python38\chargepoint.py", line 28, in main
    async with websockets.connect(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 517, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 535, in __await_impl__
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1030, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1010, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 924, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 702, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 808, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 595, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 1225] The remote computer refused the network connection
>>>
```

Comment: The 2nd part is a totally different question. First was about installing *OCPP* under *Python 2*, 2nd is a runtime one. Please keep them separate, and mark the answer (if it solved your problem) as a solution to the 1st question (this one), and submit another for the 2nd part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[PyPI]: ocpp](https://pypi.org/project/ocpp) (currently *v0.8.1*) only supports *Python **3***. However, same thing applies to *v0.1.1* (very 1<sup>st</sup> *OCPP* version).

So, the only way to proceed is install (and start using) *Python 3*, and give up *Python 2(.7)* (who is dead from the beginning of allmighty 2020 ([[Python]: PEP 373 - Python 2.7 Release Schedule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373))).

Of course, there's the (painful) alternative of porting *OCPP* code to *Python 2*, but I'd totally advice against it.

Comment: ok i will try install python3 and install ocpp thanks for your advice

Comment: @vijayakumarsargunam: let me know how that works out.

Comment: hi CristiFi sorry for the delayed response. yes the answer satisfies my question no doubt about it. thanks

Comment: @vijayakumarsargunam: then could you please accept it (mark it as a solution)?